# Use PHP to get the values of custom internal XML Entities

Tags: php, xml, entity, domdocument, doctype

I have an XML file with the following Document Type Declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE Credits SYSTEM "http://www.mrinitialman.com/././DTD-XSD/./mrinitialman.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY fa "http://www.furaffinity.net/user/">
    <!ENTITY da ".deviantart.com/">
    <!ENTITY weasyl "https://www.weasyl.com/~">
    <!ENTITY tweet "https://twitter.com/">
    <!ENTITY wiki-en "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
    <!ENTITY hymnarybio "https://hymnary.org/person/">
    <!ENTITY kerkliedwiki "https://kerkliedwiki.nl/">
    <!ENTITY wiki-nl "https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
]>
```

My PHP is simply ignoring all entity references; for example instead of seeing the attribute `url="&wiki-en;Anne_Steele"` and sending along "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Steele", the code simply sends along "Anne_Steele", which causes my hyperlinks to not work.

So, I'd like to try a workaround in which I have PHP read all the Entities and get their text values, and go from there.

The problem is, I'm not getting anything.

For example: should I try the following:

```
$entityarray=array();
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->LoadXML(xmlfile.xml);
$entities = $xml->doctype->entities;
for($entity_num = 0; $entity_num < $entities->length; $entity_num++){
    $entity = $entities->item($entity_num);
    $entity_name = $entity->nodeName;
    $entityarray[$entity_name] = $xml->SaveXML($entity);
}
```

I get an associated array of the *whole* Entity (for example, `<!ENTITY wiki-en "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/">`)

If, however, I try this:

```
for($entity_num = 0; $entity_num < $entities->length; $entity_num++){
    $entity = $entities->item($entity_num);
    $entity_name = $entity->nodeName;
    $entityarray[$entity_name] = $entity->nodeValue;
}
```

or

```
for($entity_num = 0; $entity_num < $entities->length; $entity_num++){
    $entity = $entities->item($entity_num);
    $entity_name = $entity->nodeName;
    $entityarray[$entity_name] = $entity->textContent;
}
```

I get an associated array of empty strings.  Do I need to trim the entity code down to what I want?  Is there something else I should do?  Or am I just wasting my time struggling with Entity references?

---

### Addendum:

I think I found out why I was having trouble: `DOMDocument::importNode()` and `DOMNode::appendChild()`  Here is the full code:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<!DOCTYPE Credits [
     <!ENTITY da ".deviantart.com/">
     <!ENTITY wiki-en "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
     <!ENTITY wiki-nl "https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
]> <root attribute="&wiki-en;?test">&da;</root>
XML;

$xml2 = <<<'XML'
<!DOCTYPE check [
     <!ENTITY wiki-nl "https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
]>
<check>&wiki-nl;</check>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument(); 
$document->substituteEntities=true;
$document->loadXML($xml); 

$document2 = new DOMDocument();
$document2->substituteEntities=true;
$document2->loadXML($xml2); 
$document->documentElement->appendChild($document->importNode($document2->documentElement));


var_dump($document->documentElement->textContent);
var_dump($document->documentElement->getAttribute('attribute'));
var_dump($document2->documentElement->textContent);
var_dump($document->getElementsByTagName('check')->item(0)->textContent);
```

Output: string(16) ".deviantart.com/" string(35) "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?test" string(30) "nl.wikipedia.org/wiki" string(0) ""

Note: The content of the imported node is blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading string values from a DOM (`$textContent`, `getAttribute()`) the entities will be resolved. Here is a small example:

```php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<!DOCTYPE Credits [
    <!ENTITY da ".deviantart.com/">
    <!ENTITY wiki-en "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
]>
<root attribute="&wiki-en;?test">&da;</root>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);

// reading string values - the entities are resolved
var_dump($document->documentElement->textContent);
var_dump($document->documentElement->getAttribute('attribute'));
```

Output:

```php
string(16) ".deviantart.com/"
string(35) "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?test"
```

Setting `DOMDocument::$substituteEntities` will replace all entities during parsing.

```php
$document = new DOMDocument();
// let the parser replace the entities
$document->substituteEntities = true;
$document->loadXML($xml);

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Credits [
<!ENTITY da ".deviantart.com/">
<!ENTITY wiki-en "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
]>
<root attribute="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?test">.deviantart.com/</root>
```

Comment: I hope it's okay if I ask my question in multiple comments.  I think I found out why I was having trouble:  ```DOMDocument::importNode()``` and ```DOMNode::appendChild()```

First part of my code:
```$xml = <<<'XML'
<!DOCTYPE Credits [
    <!ENTITY da ".deviantart.com/">
    <!ENTITY wiki-en "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
    <!ENTITY wiki-nl "https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
]>
<root attribute="&wiki-en;?test">&da;</root>
XML;

$xml2 = <<<'XML'
<!DOCTYPE check [
    <!ENTITY wiki-nl "https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
]>
<check>&wiki-nl;</check>
XML;
```

Comment: Second part:  ```$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$document->substituteEntities=true;

$document2 = new DOMDocument();
$document2->loadXML($xml2);
$document2->substituteEntities=true;

$document->documentElement->appendChild($document->importNode($document2->documentElement));```

Comment: Third part and output:
```var_dump($document->documentElement->textContent);
var_dump($document->documentElement->getAttribute('attribute'));
var_dump($document2->documentElement->textContent);
var_dump($document->getElementsByTagName('check')->item(0)->textContent);```

**Output:**  string(16) ".deviantart.com/" string(35) "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?test" string(30) "https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/" string(0) "" **Note:** The content of the imported node is blank.

Comment: That is not really readable. Please edit you question or ask a new specific one (if it is different enough). Try to make the example self contained (so that other can execute it). Parser options like `substituteEntities` have to be set before the `load()` (before you use the parser). If you copy the entity reference node into a new document without the DTD I would not be surprised if it becomes unknown.

Comment: Okay, question edited to add what I tried to post in the comments.

Comment: You missed the second argument of `importNode()`. You only copy the element node itself, not its descendants. This includes the text nodes.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Still not sure why it didn't work in my HTML generation, but I think I can figure it out.